# PHP how to get files from a folder in a specific extention

Tags: php, image, png

I'm trying to get all of the files inside a folder with the `.png` extension, then `echo` the image onto the screen. Here's my current code:

```
$files = glob('/path/to/dir/*.png');
foreach($files as $file){
    echo '<a href="art/'.$file.'">';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor tags are for hyperlinks not images. You need to be using image tags like...

```
<img src="art/'.$file.'" />
```